# AWS MQTT Server Authentication with CA Certificate

Tags: aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to establish mutual X.509 certificate authentication between the MQTT client and AWS IoT.

On the [X.509 Certificates and AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-device-certs.html) page, it is mentioned that one can

> reference the CA root certificate in your device code when you connect to AWS IoT. For more information, see the AWS IoT Device SDKs.

However, when I look through the [documentation for the Java SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java) as well as the [API documentation](http://aws-iot-device-sdk-java-docs.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/), I see no mention of how to do this. I have downloaded the CA Certificate, but I do not see where I can pass this in when setting up the AWSIoTMqttClient():

```
this.client = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, pair.keyStore, pair.keyPassword);
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?